# Time series data on construction cost

Tags: data-request, time-series, prices

I am looking for some time-series data on construction costs in Australian property markets. 
Ideally the data would have information including city, property type (industrial, residential, etc), and $/sqm. Any relevant data would be welcome, even if it isn't specific to Australia.

Answer (score 4):

Check out these databases on Quandl:

- Australian Bureau of Statistics: 
  https://www.quandl.com/data/AUSBS?keyword=construction
- Organisation for Economic Co-Operation and Development with data on Australia: https://www.quandl.com/data/OECD?keyword=construction%20cost%20australia
- National Institute of Statistics and Economic Studies with data on France:
  https://www.quandl.com/data/INSEE?keyword=construction%20cost

Hope these help you get started.

[Disclosure: I work for Quandl]